# Case from select with null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have lot of data and for sample purpose mention below data

```
    d1  date                        OL
    N   2012-03-09 00:00:00.000     NULL
    No  2011-09-26 00:00:00.000     OL
    N   2012-01-26 00:00:00.000     NOL
    N   2012-03-07 00:00:00.000     NOL
    yes 2012-02-23 00:00:00.000     NULL
```

i need to wrire sp like

```
Create proc dbo.usp_all_property_search
(@type varchar(2))
as
begin
select * from tbl where ol is
select case @type
when 'o' then null
else
not null
end

end
```

Plz help me .

Comment: What does your SP not do that you need help with?

Comment: It will be helpful if you would explain what you are trying to do, what result are you looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're over complicating it:

```
SELECT *
FROM Tbl
WHERE (@type = 'o' AND ol IS NULL)
OR (@Type <> 'o' AND ol IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from tbl
where (@type = 'o' and ol is null) OR
    (@type <> 'o' and ol is not null)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
select * from tbl where (@type = 'o' and ol is null) or (@type != 'o' and ol is not null)
```

Case *expressions* have to return a *value*, and SQL Server doesn't even support a boolean datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
Create proc dbo.usp_all_property_search
(@type varchar(2))
as
begin
select * from tbl 
where (@type = 'o' and ol is null)
OR (@type != 'o' AND ol is not null)

end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Create proc dbo.usp_all_property_search(@type varchar(2))
as
begin
  select * 
  from tbl 
  where 
     ( @type = 'o' and
       ol is null)        or
     ( @type != 'o' and
       ol is not null);
end
```